# Estimote Nearables

Tags: swift, ibeacon, estimote

All,

I am trying to find the proximity of a nearable. I am constructing a switch statement to check if its near, intermidetate, far etc. I am working in Swift.

I have ranged my nearable and I am in a delegate method :

```
 func nearableManager(manager: ESTNearableManager!, didRangeNearable nearable: ESTNearable!) {
    self.nearable = nearable
 }
```

When I try and get Zone it doesn't find it, so nearable.zone is not found - I don't know what is wrong. Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not found", is it 0? (i.e. ESTNearableZoneUnknown)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599486/arc-unavailable-methods-in-swift)

Seems like Swift compiler doesn't want to use `zone` method as for some reason it assumes that you want to call `zone` method from `NSObject`, which returns `NSZone *` struct and can not be used in ARC environment.

I fixed this problem with introducing a category with one new method which returns value from the old one.

I Added this category to **Bridging Header**. It worked fine.

```
#import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>

@interface ESTNearable (Ex)

/// Solving the compiler problem that "zone" method is unavailable in Swift
@property (readonly) ESTNearableZone nearableZone;

@end

// Implementation

@implementation ESTNearable (Ex)

- (ESTNearableZone)nearableZone
{
    return self.zone;
}

@end
```

After that I just used `nearableZone` method in **Swift**

```
var zone = someNearable.nearableZone
```