# ARC unavailable methods in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I was able to see an interesting case using
[Estimote nearables SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK)

They have a class `ESTNearable` with property called `zone`.

```
// ENUM
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ESTNearableZone ) {
   ESTNearableZoneUnknown = 0,
   ESTNearableZoneImmediate,
   ESTNearableZoneNear,
   ESTNearableZoneFar,
};

// CLASS
@interface ESTNearable : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding>
// ... 
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) ESTNearableZone zone;
// ...
@end
```

So when I try to use this method in **Swift**, compiler fails with that error:
[image]

As I understand there is some kind of compiler bug and for some reason it believes that I want to use old `zone` method  from `NSObject` `- (struct _NSZone *)zone OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;` I can use other specific properties of that class without any problems.

As I use an SDK I can not change the name of the `zone` method. I believe I can write some kind of obj-c category, add some new method there, which will return value of original one, but I do not want to add obj-c classes in my project.

Is there any possibility to call this method from swift as I believe correct `zone` method will be called for class instances?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would turning off ARC for that file alone using `-fno-objc-arc` as compile flags work?

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I believe it is not allowed to disable ARC for swift files

Comment: If you specify zone as an ESTNearableZone instead of letting the compiler decide, that might help the compiler choose the correct zone method to use.

Comment: I tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the same question. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613330/1067980) more deeply there. I could not find something more good, so I went ahead with my old assumptions.

I Added this category to **Bridging Header**. It worked fine.

```
#import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>

@interface ESTNearable (Ex)

/// Solving the compiler problem that "zone" method is unavailable in Swift
@property (readonly) ESTNearableZone nearableZone;

@end

// Implementation

@implementation ESTNearable (Ex)

- (ESTNearableZone)nearableZone
{
    return self.zone;
}

@end
```

After that I just used `nearableZone` method in **Swift**

```
var zone = someNearable.nearableZone
```